# backbone routes - ordering and filtering

Tags: backbone.js, routes

In my Backbone app, on my collection I have numerous sorting methods, when rendering the views based on the collection I am currently using a global var set via the route (I do it with a global as other actions add to the collection and I want the last ordering to be used).  For example

```
routes : {
    "" : "index",           
    '/ordering/:order' : 'ordering'
},
ordering : function(theorder) {
    ordering = theorder;
    listView.render();  
},
```

then in my view

```
if (typeof ordering === 'undefined') {
    d = this.collection.ordered();          
} 
else if(ordering == 'owners') {
    d = this.collection.owners();
} 

_.each(d, function(model){          
    model.set({request : self.model.toJSON()});
    var view = new TB_BB.OfferItemView({model : model});
    els.push(view.render().el);
});
```

Where ordered and owners are the 2 ordering methods.

So my first question is, based on routes could someone advice a better way of implementing above? This view gets rendered in multiple places hence me using a global rather than passing a ordered var to the method?

Second question is - I would like to also add some filtering, so lets say I want to sort by 'price' but also do some filtering (lets say by multiple categories id).  How could I add a flexible 'route' to deal with filtering.

I guess I could do

```
routes : {
    "" : "index",
    '/ordering/:order/:filter1/:filter2' : 'ordering'
},
```

So the filter1 and filter2 would be the subsequent filtering, but if the filters could be 0 or 100 this will not work. Could anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first you should be using Backbone's built-in ability to auto-sort collections. You can take advantage of this by defining a [`comparator`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator) function on your collection. This gives you all kinds of wins right out of the box — for example, the collection will re-sort itself every time you add or remove something from it, based on your `comparator`. If you want to define multiple sort functions, just define them all as functions and then update `comparator` when you need to. Then you can ditch that ugly global `var`.

For your second question, I'm not totally sure what you mean by "if the filters could be 0 or 100 this will not work." If you mean that you'll run into trouble if you don't specifiy *all* of the filters, then that's true. But you can use a wildcard to fix that. Here's what that might look like:

```
// your routes look like this:
routes : {
    '/ordering/:order/filters/*filters' : 'ordering' // your routes will look like: /ordering/price/filters/filter_one/filter_two/filter_three
},
ordering: function (order, filters) {
  filters = filters.split('/'); // creates an array of filters: ['filter_one', 'filter_two', 'filter_three']
  listView.render(filters); // pass your filters to the view
}

// listView.render() looks like this:
render: function(filters) {
  collection = this.collection;
  _.each(filters, function (filter) {
    collection = collection.filter(function () {
      // your actual filtering code based on what the filter is
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Josh, the comparator seems to do exactly what I need! as does the filtering!